# Redirect output from C to Matlab

Tags: c, linux, matlab

I'm using Linux & Matlab R2017.

I have a C program, which have an infinite output via `printf()`, which I want to direct to matlab.

I'm able to run this program like this `unix('./prog'),` 
after that I have output, but I dont know how to save it to matlab array.

Actually, I want to make it like FIFO, but no idea how..
As I know in matlab no pipes like in bash.

Answer (score 0):

It is only loosely related with C language. IMHO, the only C point is that you need to make sure whether stdout can be buffered in your C program. It it should not be, you will have to either explicitely set it unbuffered (`setbuff(stdout, NULL);`) or `fflush` is when you need to output to be immediately available.

For the rest, I would use a fifo file at the file system level. Such a fifo can be created with `mkfifo fifo_path`. Then you ask your matlab program to read its input from the fifo and redirect the output of your C program there: `unix('./prog > /path/to/fifo')`

Comment: it's a good solution, but how can I flush the pipe? it's increasing size.. 
I've made a pipe. and run C program at terminal ./prog > PIPE;
in C I have `fd = open(portname, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_SYNC); for (p = buf; rdlen-- > 0; p++) printf("%hu ", *p);`
Then I'm able to read it in matlab, just like a file. But how can I flush it?